# Change ALL html tags to symbol using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

What I want to do is change every tag (whether its `<a href=>` or `<title>` or `</title>` or `</div>`... etc) to a symbol.

I tried using beautiful soup but it only finds tags that I define...

I found some code in the HTMLparser.py

```
tagfind = re.compile('([a-zA-Z][^\t\n\r\f />\x00]*)(?:\s|/(?!>))*')
```

I beleive this is what I'm looking for I just dont know how to use it properly.

Also I figured I could use the:

```
handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
```

But I don't want to define the tag, I just want the script to find every single tag and change it to something...

Is this possible?

Thank you for all of your help!!

Comment: That's a lot of tags. What's your ultimate goal?

Comment: To remove EVERY tag from the HTML and replace them with a symbol

Comment: I mean why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup isn't a good idea here - that's designed for *parsing* HTML, not editing it.

Also, that regex doesn't seem like a very good one (only matches the content *inside* a tag rather than the whole tag itself) so I found a different one that would be better suited to your purposes:

```
</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[\^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>
```

This tag will match anything like the following:

```
<h1>
</h1>
<img src="foo.com/image.png">
```

We can use this for replacing all tags by using `re.sub`. This finds all matches for a certain regex and replaces them with something else. Here's how you'd use it for what you want to do:

```
import re

html_regex = r"""</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[\^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>"""
html = "<h1>Foo</h1>"

print(re.sub(html_regex, "@", html))
```

This would print:

```
@Foo@
```

Comment: @HarpAngell No problem! Please remember to accept answers that have helped you.

Comment: just missing an ending ) on the print function, but it works!!

Comment: @HarpAngell That tag is replaced for me. Can you please post a Pastebin link to the full HTML that's not working?

Answer (score 1):

A much more reliable way is to recursively visit each tag, I just changed the name in the example below but you can do whatever you want once you have the tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element

def visit(s):
    if isinstance(s, element.Tag):
        has_children = s.find_all()
        if has_children:
            s.name = "foobar"
            for child in s:
                visit(child)
        else:
            s.name = "foobar"
```

To use it:

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(...)
 visit(soup)
```

Then any changes will be reflected in the soup.

Comment: @HarpAngell, what tag are you talking about? You just pass the soup to the function and do whatever you want when you find a tag, run the code on some html and then print soup after

Comment: You said "once you have the tag" but now i realize you mean once the script has the tag

Comment: Once `if isinstance(s, element.Tag)` is True you have a tag so each s is the tag inside the if/else, you can do whatever you like with it and it wil be a lot more reliable than a regex

Comment: url = os.path.abspath('test.html')            
sock = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(sock,'html.parser')
soup = visit(soup)

print soup

Comment: It happens  in place,  don't assign just call visit on the soup object